# np.savetxt not saving all rows in 3D matrix when using f=open(...)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D array of shape (10000, 3) created like so:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(100)
xs = np.random.randint(1, 10000, 10000)
ys = np.random.randint(1, 10000, 10000)
rs = np.random.randint(1, 100, 10000)
data = np.vstack([xs, ys, zs]).T
np.shape(data)  # (10000, 3)
```

Now when I save using the following, it seems to only save the first 9690 lines:

```
f = open('data.txt','w')
np.savetxt(f, data, fmt='%i')
b = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=int)
np.shape(b)   # (9690, 3)
```

But when I pass in the filename directly, it saves everything:

```
np.savetxt('data.txt', data, fmt='%i')
b = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=int)
np.shape(b)  # (10000, 3)
```

I actually wanted to use `f = open('input_rand.txt','a')` because I had two arrays (different shapes) I wanted to save in the same text file, but it seems like if I use the `open` function it doesn't save everything I want it to. What am I missing? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Close your file after saving:

```
f = open('data.txt','w')
np.savetxt(f, data, fmt='%i')
f.close()
b = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=int)
np.shape(b)
```

even better, use context manager:

```
with open('data.txt','w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, data, fmt='%i')

b = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=int)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But why do you need to close it & it is that when you don't close it the last 310 rows are missing?

Comment: It is normal to close a open file; though you can get by with letting the script finish. In Python3 we are encouraged to use a `with open() as f`: context when writing to file.  That ensures that the file is closed in timely fashion.  In any case, it is not a good idea to read a file while it is still be written.